# Konvajs + vuejs How to save changed height width of elements

Tags: vue.js, konvajs

I am trying to resize elements in canavas using konva js plugin concept. But the resized width and height are not saved to database. My actual height width are not being replaced by resized height widths for any of the elements whether a image,layer,stage

Answer (score 0):

Do you change sizes with `Konva.Transformer` (https://konvajs.org/docs/vue/Transformer.html)?

If so - `Transformer` tool doesn't change `width` and `height` directly. Instead, it is changing `scaleX` and `scaleY` of a node. So you just need to save that attrs too into a database or change `width`/`height` to match new scaling:

```js
const newWidth = rectangle.width() * rectangle.scaleX();
// set new width
rectangle.width(newWidth);

// reset scale:
rectangle.scaleX(1);
```